# Backbone with Jade issues with tag parameters

Tags: backbone.js, pug

Very annoying problem I'm facing.  I want to dynamically enter the url of an image using backbone.  I thought the following would do.

```
img(src="<%= image %>" width="100%" height="auto")
```

However the src url does not get replaced correctly and stays as "<%= image %>" when I do:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this and have the jade syntax intact.This way the underscore variable can be referred directly.

```
  img(src!="<%= image %>" width="100%" height="auto")
```

Comment: Thanks :) Worked like a charm.